# base64 encode result are different in dart and java

Tags: java, dart, encoding, base64

I am trying to encode xml to base64 but result in dart and java are different from each other.
I have checked from https://www.base64encode.org/ website it gives same result as java.

```
    byte[] array = invoiceHashValue_WithQRHash.getBytes();
    String invoiceEncodeData = new String(Base64.encode(array, Base64.DEFAULT));

     // dart code  
    List<int> array = invoiceHashValue_WithQRHash.codeUnits;
    String invoiceEncodeData = base64Encode(array);
```

Comment: Your dart code units are UTF-16, while your online encoder defaults to UTF-8. Java probably as well. You're completely ignoring character encoding. Then you mentioned that this is supposed to be XML, so probably worthwhile to look into XML canonicalization as well.

Answer (score 2):

Dart's `Base64` encoding encodes *bytes* and a string's `codeUnits` are not bytes. They're UTF-16 code units. If the string contains only ASCII, or maybe even only iso-8859-1 characters (UTF-16 code units with values <= 255), then it'll probably do something reasonable. If not, the `Base64.encode` will probably just truncate every code unit to the lower 8 bits.

So you want to convert the string to bytes. The page you link to use UTF-8 encoding as default, so that's what I'd do here too:

```dart
List<int> array = utf8.encode(invoiceHashValue_WithQRHash);
String invoiceEncodeData = base64.encode(array);
```

If you're going to do the same operation repeatedly, you can combine the codecs into one:

```dart
var base64Utf8 = utf8.fuse(base64); // First to last in encoding order.
// ...
String invoceEncodeData = base64Utf8.encode(invoiceHashValue_WithQRHash);
```

Doing this gives me the same result as the page you linked to for strings containing non-ASCII characters.